# Variable memory address attribution EXEC_BAD_ACESS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, pointers, nsdate, exc-bad-access

I have an allocated object where its attributes are store in the following memory places:
[image: Memory status]

When I make a simple attribution of the `NSDate` attribute to a variable it gives me an `EXEC_BAD_ACESS`.
As you can see from the first image only the date attribute and the `fileDate` variable have different addresses.

[image: EXEC_BAD_ACESS]

Am I making some pointer related error?
The other 2 attributes are assigned correctly to the variables, it only happens with the `NSDate` so maybe I'm missing some detail about `NSDate`.

EDIT1

`DownloadFile` definition:
[image: DownloadFile]

EDIT2

init function:
[image]

EDIT3
date parameter:

[image: date]

Comment: Please show the definition of the date property and the `DownloadFile` class.

Comment: Is currDFile.date is string??

Comment: property and allocation of NSDate?

Comment: Edited to add the the DownloadFile class.

Comment: @SimonePistecchia don't see why allocation is relevant... it exists in memory, they have the same data type it is just about memory pointer assigning I think. Can you elaborate why would that be relevant?

Comment: Can you show your `init` method and do you override `setDate:` or `date` at all?

Comment: @Reonarudo: It's relevant if you aren't using ARC and you haven't properly allocated the `NSDate` in a way where you have explicitly accepted ownership of the object.

Comment: Do you override `setDate:` or `date` if so can we see the implementation

Comment: @Reonarudo so i'd read only now, but i think now you understand what i meant...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there any reason why you are not using ARC? There are quite a few memory management errors there causing leaks and one that should cause your crash.

```
NSDate *dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:receivedDate];
```

returns an autoreleased `NSDate` so when you then call the additional

```
[dateFromString autorelease];
```

you are overreleasing the `NSDate` hence your crash.

---

```
[pFile setDate:[[NSDate alloc] init]];
```

is a memory leak. Going through the setter `setDate:` will cause `pFile` to take a +1 retain on the date, which it should release in it's `dealloc`. The `[[NSDate alloc] init]` call returns a date object with +1 but is then never released elsewhere.

You can fix this either with

```
[NSDate date]
```

Or

```
[[[NSDate alloc] init] autorelease];
```

The first option is preferred

Comment: Yes you are right. I did not notice the extra autorelease. Thank you.

Comment: Also it's worth noting that although it works it's not semantically correct to compare an object pointer to `Nil` in your line `dateFromString != Nil` you should prefer the all lower case `nil`. Check out [NSHipster](http://nshipster.com/nil/) for more info

Comment: How do you suggest I go around the `[pFile setDate:[[NSDate alloc] init]];` ?

Comment: I showed you both ways in my answer... either `[pFile setDate:[NSDate date]];` or `[pFile setDate:[[[NSDate alloc] init] autorelease]];`